# Not able to generate sub menus of pure css tiered drop down with mysql

Tags: php, css, mysqli

I'm trying to create a drop down menu which works with pure css. This works perfectly in HTML without any issues, but when I try to take the information out of my SQL tables, I seem to hit hurdles. I will try to explain the problem as concisely as I can.

HTML without PHP/Mysqli

```
<div id='menu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li cl ass='active has-sub'>
            <a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'>
                    <a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

HTML with PHP/Mysqli

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="">Properties</a>
        <ul>
            <?php 
                require_once 'connect.php';
                $qry = db_select("select city as city,name from property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id left join city c on b.city_id=c.id group by city");
                foreach ($qry as $row) {
                    echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>".$row['city']."</span></a></li>";
                }
                echo "<ul>";
                $qry = db_select("select city as city,name from property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id left join city c on b.city_id=c.id ");
                foreach ($qry as $row) {
                    echo "<li><a href='#'><span>".$row['name']."</span></a></li>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This shows all the cities correctly but all properties (name) are not shown as sub menus but just after all the cities.

I know what the issue is but don't know how to solve it.

Basically because I have a foreach it is making multiple (or none) `<UL>` tags when I need only one for each set. I am not sure how to do this. Hope somebody can help.

I haven't put the CSS because I don't think it is relevant here, but if required I can also put that.

Comment: Please take care of your code indentation, it is highly confusing to see the code which is not structured, also it is difficult to understand the issue in  first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear about what menu structure you actually want, but it's sure that you are missing couple of closing tags.

```
<li class="has-sub"><a href="">Properties</a>    
<ul>
<?php 
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $qry = db_select("select city as city,name from property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id left join city c on b.city_id=c.id group by city");
    foreach ($qry as $row)
    {
        echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>".$row['city']."</span></a></li>";
    }
    echo "<ul>"; //this seems the issue, should be </ul></li>
?>
```

Still, I'm a bit unclear about the actual menu structure you are trying to achieve. But try to point out the closing tags properly, that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps.

```
<ul>
<?php 
            require_once 'connect.php';
            $qry = db_select("select city as city,name from property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id left join city c on b.city_id=c.id group by city");
            foreach ($qry as $row) : ?>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?php echo $row['city']; ?></span></a>

               <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span><?php  echo $row['name']; ?></span></a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it but I found an answer by making sure the first record of each set shows a `<UL>` but not the rest.

Basically this is done by the following

> 1. variable as true
> 2. if variable true then "do something" variable is false
> 3. else "do something else"

I have also added classes in the UL and Li but that is not relevant.

This works but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. I haven't tried the other ways, but I would like an opinion whether this is a good way as it is working.

```
<li class="has-sub"><a href=""><span>Properties</span></a>
 <?php 
      $qry=db_select("select distinct city from city a join area b on a.id=b.city_id join property c on b.id=c.area_id");


    $first=true;
                   foreach ($qry as $row)
    {

        $city=$row['city'];
    if ($first)
    {
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?php echo $row['city']; ?></span></a>



        <?php
        $first=false;
        }else{
        ?>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span><?php echo $row['city']; ?></span></a>
    <?php
        }
             $city=$row['city'];


      $qry=db_select("select city,a.id as id,name from property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id left join city c on b.city_id=c.id where city='$city' ");
        $first=true;


      foreach ($qry as $row)
    {


    if ($first)
    {
    ?>
           <ul class="drop_ul"><li class="drop_col"><a href="showprop.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span></a></li>
    <?php 
     $first=false;
     }
     else{
            ?>

            <li class="drop_col"><a href="showprop.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span></a></li>
          <?php
              }}?>
    </ul>
    </li>
              <?php
              }
              ?>

                    </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is some errors : 
 - 2  against 1 
 - there is no  for the item Properties
 - the nomber of

  < number of

let me now about the structure of your menu, is it like this?
**Main** 
**About Us** 
**Projects** 
**Properties** >> 
                 county >> 
                          name 1 
                          name 2
                           ...
                          name i

Comment: Properties menu - city (from sql) submenu - property name (from sql) sub menu item